# While loop in a If loop in a while loop

Tags: c++

In the following code I am having this problem,when i run through it the first time it works just fine, but on subsequent loops when I choose option 1 nothing shows up just goes back to the "menu", it only works the first time, no time after that, can someone explain the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice=0;
    while(choice != 2){
        cout << "(1)Create" << endl;
        cout << "(2)Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1){
            int choice2;
            while(choice2 != 7){
                cout << "You chose one " << endl;
                cin >> choice2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're in luck! Today on stackoverflow.com we're running a one-time only promotion called "Answer Your Own Question Day". We have secretly placed on your computer a highly advanced tool called a "debugger". Using this state-of-the-art technology, you can step through your program as it executes, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables, and determine why exactly your code is doing what it's doing, all by yourself! Don't miss this exciting opportunity to answer your own question. Only today, on stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Is that necessary?, I am new to this and I am having trouble, this is a logic problem not a code problem so debugger wont help

Comment: @Xavier can you provide the sample input that you gave. Also provide the sample output that you got.

Comment: This is exactly what a debugger is for: to observe the program's logic, and how the execution proceeds, and why. Use a debugger to verify the values of all variables, how each if/while statement evaluates, etc... Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior because you perform evaluation against `choice2` in the inner while-loop conditional without ever setting a value for it. Its value is thusly *indeterminate* and any evaluation (assignment, comparison, whatever) invokes *undefined behavior*. Ask yourself this: what value does `choice2` have on the initial entry into `while(choice2 != 7)` ? The only valid answer is "I haven't a clue" , and neither does your program. You didn't make that mistake on your outer loop with `choice`, so it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but this worked for me fine... (really the same code, just neater).

```
int main()
{   
int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "(1)Create" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(2)Exit" << std::endl;

        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            int choice2 = 0;

            while (choice2 != 7)
            {
                std::cout << "You chose one " << std::endl;
                std::cin >> choice2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help nrocboc somehow than choice2=0 makes all of the difference do you have any idea why this is

Comment: choice2 was never being set back to something other than 7.

Comment: thank you for your help and not being a saracastic *******

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be, you didn't initialize choice2 variable after declaration and that means it contains garbage values.

Comment: nrocboc exaplained that to me but one thing I dont get if choice2 contained garbage values when i pressed one why did it just skip the entire while loop rather than get caught in an infinite loop, just curious

Comment: when you entered 1 for choice 2 in the inside while loop it will not get into infinite loop, it will wait for you to give another choice2 at cin>>choice2 because choice2!=7, once try and use the debugging you will understand the problem